# "Undefined property: stdClass::$name" unable to read data from ng-model?? (Angularjs, php, mysql)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

I´m trying to add some data to my data base via a form. But I get errors in console

`"Undefined property: stdClass::$name in ..."` (this error is in `create.php` line 6.) I get this error for every line I try to read data from (picture below). I am unable to understand why it is not working.

**Console ERROR messages**

[image]

**create.php**

```
<?php
include '../src/config/db2.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$advertiser_name = $data->name;
$advertiser_org = $data->orgnumber;
$advertiser_phone = $data->phone;
$advertiser_address = $data->address;
$advertiser_postcode = $data->postcode;
$advertiser_location = $data->location;
$advertiser_billAddress = $data->billAddress;
$advertiser_billPostcode = $data->billPostcode;
$advertiser_billLocation = $data->billLocation;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_advertisers` (
  `advertiser_name`,
  `advertiser_org`,
  `advertiser_phone`,
  `advertiser_address`,
  `advertiser_postcode`,
  `advertiser_location`,
  `advertiser_billAddress`,
  `advertiser_billPostcode`,
  `advertiser_billLocation`)
  VALUES (
    '$advertiser_name',
    '$advertiser_org',
    '$advertiser_phone',
    '$advertiser_address',
    '$advertiser_postcode',
    '$advertiser_location',
    '$advertiser_billAddress',
    '$advertiser_billPostcode',
    '$advertiser_billLocation')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Data added";
    }
    else {
      echo "Error: Did not add data $sql" .mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container wrapper">

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <h3 class="">Add Company Information</h3>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">

      <form >
        <div ng-show="msg">
          <strong>Success!</strong> Company Added!.
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="advertiser_name">Company name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_name" ng-model="advertiser_name" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_org">Company number</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_org" ng-model="advertiser_org" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_phone">Phone</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_phone" ng-model="advertiser_phone" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_address">Address</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_address" ng-model="advertiser_address" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_postcode">Postcode</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_postcode" ng-model="advertiser_postcode" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_location">Post Area</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_location" ng-model="advertiser_location" />
        </div>

        <br/>

        <h3>Billing Information</h3>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_billAddress">Address</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_billAddress" ng-model="advertiser_billAddress" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_billPostcode">Postcode</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_billPostcode" ng-model="advertiser_billPostcode" />
        </div>

        <div >
          <label for="advertiser_billLocation">Post Area</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="advertiser_billLocation" ng-model="advertiser_billLocation" />
        </div>

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add_company()">Submit</button>
        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-warning" >Go Back</a>
      </form>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Playercontroller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('crudApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $timeout, 
$location) {

  $scope.add_company = function(){

    $scope.msg=false;
    //set the data array
    console.log($scope.msg);
    //use $http.post to send above data to php
    $http.post('php/create.php', {

      'name':$scope.advertiser_name,
      'orgnumber':$scope.advertiser_org,
      'phone':$scope.advertiser_phone,
      'address':$scope.advertiser_address,
      'postcode':$scope.advertiser_postcode,
      'location':$scope.advertiser_location,
      'billAddress':$scope.advertiser_billAddress,
      'billPostcode':$scope.advertiser_billPostcode,
      'billLocation':$scope.advertiser_billLocation


    }).then(function(response){
      //clear the form fields
      $scope.msg = true;
      $timeout(function(){$scope.msg = false;}, 1000);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
    console.log($scope.advertiser_name);
  };


});
```

Comment: Title needs translation, too.

Comment: The data may not be as json, which means the json_decode would fail. The best way to check would be to log/dump `file_get_contents("php://input")` and `$data`

Comment: i changed it and got this error: " Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in ..."

Comment: What do you get if you log/dump the file_get_contents?

Comment: i got "undefined"